# java.lang.ClassCircularityError while deploying artifact on server

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

when I run tomcat server, while deploying the artifact, I am getting two errors.
First error is:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(LogisticsServices.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: LogisticsServices.log (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileNotFoundException: LogisticsServices.log (Access is denied)
```

Second error is :

```
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
```

I checked the permission of the LogisticsServices.log file and changed permission to full control for users.Still same error is occuring. 
And when I search for the ClassCircularityError, I could not get any relevant info. I am not sure what is actual error in both these and what should I do to fix this.I am attaching full stack trace of the error
Any help would be great

```
15:32:13,126 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(LogisticsServices.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: LogisticsServices.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: LogisticsServices.log (Access is denied)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:148)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:77)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:152)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:141)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:120)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:331)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:283)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1501)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:619)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:566)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
    at  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15:32:13,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
15:32:13,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
15:32:13,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
15:32:13,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@71b653af - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Jun 21, 2015 3:32:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 21, 2015 3:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:287)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:757)
    at sun.rmi.runtime.Log$LoggerLog.log(Log.java:228)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPConnection.close(TCPConnection.java:219)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:596)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:287)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:757)
    at sun.rmi.runtime.Log$LoggerLog.log(Log.java:228)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:770)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:287)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:757)
    at sun.rmi.runtime.Log$LoggerLog.log(Log.java:228)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:770)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-21 03:32:23,596] Artifact logistics-services:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:287)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:757)
    at sun.rmi.runtime.Log$LoggerLog.log(Log.java:228)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:770)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @Makoto,
1st thing, I am using intellij not eclipse.and I moved context listener as suggested by meriton...still it is not working

Comment: The IDE piece isn't really want I was getting at; there is [an open bug on this issue](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-740) which is referenced in one of the answers.  Further, the answers there suggest quite a few more things to attempt.